# Can I create a retention schedule for my library to another site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to for Site Collection A move all documents older than 2 years to another Site Collection (Site B).  Is this possible ?  Note I do not have access to the Central farm.

I did go to site features and activate 2 content organizer settings, but it appears I can only archive to Site Collection A.  This is problematic as we want to manage the size of our site collection A by moving old documents to site collection B and then eventually deleting the documents from B..